# Error while trying to connect to Firebase using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am following a Youtube tutorial on how to make a Whatsapp clone using android studio (link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=988UZFB0heA&t=402s). At minute 6:50, it mentions to connect to firebase. This is even before coding anything. When I do that, I get the following error:

Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.

I've seen other questions that have this error but all of them already had code within it. Mine is happening without writing anything. So, I can't post any code or follow those instructions.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have anything to do with the code at all, but rather the procedure in which you structured your project.

The problem is that you added adMob to your app before connecting to Firebase. As a result, you'll need to remove the google services plugin and re-sync your gradle file. Please complete the following steps:

1. Go to your build.gradle file in your Android Studio Project(Module)
2. Remove apply plugin: `apply plugin: com.google.gms.google-services` and click resync(will appear as a bar in the top of Android Studio).

This worked for me. Thanks.